# MySQL - Returning a random record using LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I am wondering of someone could help me out.

I want to display random 'polls' on my website, I have about 50 in my database and I want to display one different one each time the person reloads the page.

To get the poll, I am using the following SQL query .... But this gets the first one in the table ... how can I tell it to get a random 'poll'

```
SELECT * 
  FROM polls 
  LEFT JOIN pollanswers ON polls.pollID = pollanswers.pollID 
 WHERE polls.pollID = 1 
 ORDER By pollAnswerListing ASC
```

Thanks much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the pollID to some random number

```
polls.pollID = 1
```

to e.g.

```
polls.pollID = 9
```

Comment: It might be an alright solution if you've got 50 polls at any time, no more and no less. However, what if there are slightly less or more? You would then need to query the database first to find how many there are, and then provide a random poll in the second query. I'd say that the ORDER BY RAND() is a better approach.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`, and probably remove the WHERE clause, assuming `polls.pollID` is your primary key.

```
SELECT * 
FROM polls 
 LEFT JOIN pollanswers ON polls.pollID = pollanswers.pollID 
/*WHERE polls.pollID = 1*/
 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @BigJobbies Whoops, the keywords `ORDER BY` were missing above. Should have been `order by rand() limit 1`

Comment: @BigJobbies: What "hasn't worked"? The suggestion seems correct (after the 'order by' fix), so what did you get?

Comment: Ahhh, i see whats happening, It needs the polls.pollID = [number] as the pollanswers are linked to the polls table by the pollID field

Comment: I disagree with 'It needs the polls.pollID = [number]'; The left join returns a result based on left joining the two tables, and only then orders it by rand() limit 1. The statement above should work.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a Random number between 1 and 50 (assuming you have 50 polls)
and pass that to your mysql query as PollId value instead of the hard coded value 1

```
var randomId= rand(5, 50);
```

Use this randomId in your query

Comment: You can't assume, `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM polls) AS max` :)

Comment: webarto: That is true. But in the question he mentioned it is almost 50. and i am assuming the person who handles this query or website will have that sense to read the count from database. The answer is only about the mysql join value.